# Is it permissible to drink water using alcoholic bottle?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I wash alcoholic bottle and there was no alcoholic smell. If i use it as water bottle. if there was permissible(haram) issue please add reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it is permissible to drink from any kind of -cleaned- vessel as long as this vessel per se was not declared haram (even if we must say these rulings might be considered abrogated), for details also read [Prohibition from drinking water from a broken or a cracked vessel](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33479/prohibition-from-drinking-water-from-a-broken-or-a-cracked-vessel/33514#33514) and [Explanation of hadith forbidden from drinking from green jars?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43313/explanation-of-hadith-forbidden-from-drinking-from-green-jars/43318#43318). So if you washed the vessel it should be clean and therefore halal to drink from.

> I had forbidden you from the drinking (and preparation of) Nabidh in the vessels made out of leather, but (now) **you may drink in all vessels, but you do not drink an intoxicant**.
> ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/83), and similar narrations in [sunan abi Dawood](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/30), sunan an-Nasa'i [here](https://sunnah.com/nasai/51/115) and [here](https://sunnah.com/nasai/43/69))

But a good Muslim should avoid situations where he is coming close to some limits of the shari'a (dark grey zones of shari'a one could say).

> Both legal and illegal things are obvious, and in between them are (suspicious) doubtful matters. **So whoever forsakes those doubtful things lest he may commit a sin, will definitely avoid what is clearly illegal**; and whoever indulges in these (suspicious) doubtful things bravely, is likely to commit what is clearly illegal. Sins are Allah's Hima (i.e. private pasture) and whoever pastures (his sheep) near it, is likely to get in it at any moment."
> (Sahih al-Bukhari [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/34/5) and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/45), [sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/22/133) and other hadith compilations)

Therefore you should get ride of such bottles.

Also be aware that alcohol is considered najasa (the exact ruling may differ according to madhhabs) and when cleaning najasa we are asked to get ride of the taste, the colour and the smell of it. Some scholars hold the opinion that if this is not possible one can only fill them with vinegar.

Some sources the fatwas (in Arabic) [islamweb #27448](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/27448), islanonline [#8842](https://fatwa.islamonline.net/8842)